# How to properly implement setTimeout function to pulse loader

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a situation trying to implement this [pulse loader](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGKpKx) `code` into my theme pages.

As far as I've read, somehow there should be a `setTimeout (function()` implemented but not so sure how to integrate this into my `js` file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("div.loader").fadeOut( 500, function(){
            $("div#content").fadeIn( 3000);
        });
      }, 2500);
    });
```

In a few words, the pulse dot, it doesn't show up before the page content appearance, like we have in this site [example](http://goo.gl/gBKHQP), it show up in the same time (too late) almost when the content is already loaded.

My result with Live examples:
[here](http://goo.gl/9Xz6GM);

If this helps, here is the [original theme](http://goo.gl/Sfmv96) `js` sequence  from the `app.min.js` file, that should manage a `.gif` loader:

```
...
    var $doc = $(document), win = $(window), Modernizr = window.Modernizr, AnimationsArray = [];
    window.SITE = {
        init: function() {
            var self = this, content = $("#wrapper"), pl = content.find(">.preloader"), count = $("body").data("cart-count");
            favicon = new Favico({
                bgColor: "#151515",
                textColor: "#fff"
            }), favicon.badge(count), content.waitForImages(function() {
                TweenMax.to(pl, 1, {
                    autoAlpha: 0,
                    ease: Quart.easeOut,
                    onComplete: function() {
                        pl.css("display", "none");
                    }
                }); 
...
```

I've replaced `.loader` with `.sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner` resulting:

```
...
    var $doc = $(document), win = $(window), Modernizr = window.Modernizr, AnimationsArray = [];
    window.SITE = {
        init: function() {
            var self = this, content = $("#wrapper"), pl = content.find(">.sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner"), count = $("body").data("cart-count");
            favicon = new Favico({
                bgColor: "#151515",
                textColor: "#fff"
            }), favicon.badge(count), content.waitForImages(function() {
                TweenMax.to(pl, 1, {
                    autoAlpha: 0,
                    ease: Quart.easeOut,
                    onComplete: function() {
                        pl.css("display", "none");
                    }
                }); 
...
```

Also in `css` I had in the preloader section:

```
...
#wrapper .preloader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 998;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 80px 60px 0;
  background: #f9f9f9 url("../img/preloader.gif") center center no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: 55px 55px;
  -o-background-size: 55px 55px;
  -webkit-background-size: 55px 55px;
  background-size: 55px 55px;
}
.site_bars_off #wrapper .preloader {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.site_bars_off #wrapper .preloader {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 40.063em) {
  #wrapper .preloader {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
...
```

modified as follow:

```
...
#wrapper .sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner {
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gold;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: sk-pulseScaleOut 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-pulseScaleOut 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-pulseScaleOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sk-pulseScaleOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.site_bars_off #wrapper .sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.site_bars_off #wrapper .sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 40.063em) {
  #wrapper .sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
...
```

In `header.php` I've replaced:

```
...
<!-- Start Loader -->
<div class="preloader"></div>
<!-- End Loader -->
...
```

with:

```
...
<!-- Start Loader -->
<div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
<!-- End Loader -->
...
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window.onload event to make the animation instead of using a timeout. Example:

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    $(window).load(function(){ 
        $(".sk-spinner-pulse").fadeOut(500);
        $("#wrapper").css("opacity","1");
    });
});
```

window.onload waits for the document and all it's images to load.

The pulse loader should be visible once the document loads, it should be outside your #wrapper div.

Comment: hey there, a little bit offtopic but, do you have any ideas the above solution can be usefull somehow to solve this issue or AJAX content loader actually is a different concept? someone recommend me to use AJAX to load the new content but so sure if this can be applied here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/32687806/4642215)  I appreciate it