# How to keep elements on top of the loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have this pulse loader code implemented into the wordpress theme (special thanks to [@dcardoso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685605/4642215)), as follows:

`dcardoso.js` file registered in `script-calls.php`:

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    $(window).load(function(){ 
        $(".sk-spinner-pulse").fadeOut(1500);
        $("#wrapper").css("opacity","1");
    });
});
```

in the main theme `app.min.js` file, this sequence:

```
...
    var $doc = $(document), win = $(window), Modernizr = window.Modernizr, AnimationsArray = [];
    window.SITE = {
        init: function() {
            var self = this, content = $("#wrapper"), pl = content.find(">.sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner"), count = $("body").data("cart-count");
            favicon = new Favico({
                bgColor: "#151515",
                textColor: "#fff"
            }), favicon.badge(count), content.waitForImages(function() {
                TweenMax.to(pl, 1, {
                    autoAlpha: 0,
                    ease: Quart.easeOut,
                    onComplete: function() {
                        pl.css("display", "none");
                    }
                }); 
...
```

Also in `app.css`, the preloader section:

```
...
#wrapper .sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner {
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gold;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: sk-pulseScaleOut 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-pulseScaleOut 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-pulseScaleOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sk-pulseScaleOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.site_bars_off #wrapper .sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.site_bars_off #wrapper .sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 40.063em) {
  #wrapper .sk-spinner-pulse.sk-spinner {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
...
```

The main goal is to keep on top of the *pulse-loader-fading-out-background*, the logotext `<div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo">` and the menu `<nav class="pagedMenu" role="navigation">` before/while the content is loading into the page.

I've tried to modify the `z-index` values but without any good result, I think there is much more than that. At this point I was wondering, what is the best way to approach this?

[Here](http://goo.gl/Rsd2C) is a functional example and here is [my site](http://goo.gl/xGBMtI) link. Please ignore the ajaxify misbehaving, just press F5 to see the loader; actually I am looking for a workaround (not on page refresh - I am sure about that) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770490/how-to-keep-elements-non-refreshed).

Any thoughts? I appreciate it.